# Post Request works with curl but not in java using HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, authentication, curl, post

I am trying to login to a website with my account credentials with a post request. When i am using curl to do my post request everything works but when i  am trying to implement it in java with the `HttpURLConnection` it doesn't.

When i send a post request with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as a header and `username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD` as my payload to `https://******.de/login/index.php` the response contains a `Set-Cookie: Session=sodfsgpc0uefhn4sdfucnau2; path=/`.

If i take this session id now and set it as a cookie to authenticate me it works with the session id of the curl request but not with the java request.

**CURL**:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data "username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD" https://******.de/login/index.php
```

**Java**

```
String loginData = "username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD";
URL url = new URL(LOGIN_URL);
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
connection.addRequestProperty("Host", "******.de");
connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(loginData.length));
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "curl/7.55.1");

connection.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
out.write(loginData);
out.flush();
out.close();

connection.getInputStream().close();

System.out.println(connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie").split(";")[0]);
```

As you can see i have tried to use the same headers that curl uses but even then it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: No, everything works with no error. You always get a session id when visiting the site, but the session id of the java request doesnt seem to be authenticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more work i figured out that the login.php site redirects the request to another page that invalidates your session id if you don't request it with the session id returned by login.php.

So calling `connection.setFollowRedirects(false);` fixed it for me.